# API timestamp restrictions for a mobile app

Tags: ios, rest, api, security, mobile-application

Looking into implementing an API security layer for a mobile app. Using the request timestamp and rejecting requests that are old would be once of the many checks. Below are some concerns with timestamps:

1. Mobile devices can have skewed times
2. Device can have a slow connection resulting in the request arriving late to the server
3. Minimized app may not send fetch requests right away (at least on iOS)
4. Request or connection may just timeout on the device

Keeping all the above in mind, would there be certain recommendations on what the ideal timestamp threshold should be? I understand that this may require be a case by case consideration and the threshold should be set depending upon the level of security desired. Just wondering if something like this has been done before and what other parameters than above should one consider?

Comment: Why do you think rejecting messages with an "old" `Date` header value is a security implementation? Not only can header values be spoofed (especially when the value is drawn from the system time), but I'm not sure how a message with a past date would indicate a security concern. Perhaps you might want to focus on using public/private keys for hashing message bodies, using the private key as a salt. That digest could be used to provide a signature header value which would allow you to have security against man-in-the-middle attacks and would eliminate the need for a plain text password.

Comment: Using a timestamp is one of the several layers in the security algorithm I'm implementing. A timestamp guarantees that a request is recent and using the same timestamp in a hash guarantees that the timestamp isn't spoofed. My algorithm is very much inline with your suggestion above. The question is regarding the timestamp alone due to limitations on a mobile app which are often not encountered on web applications.

Comment: I'm still not sure why an "old" request is a security concern. If you wish to expire a client's ability to make a request after a certain amount of time, why not issue an access key with an expiration tied to it? If you want to make sure a request is not processed more than once, why not issue an nonce token? As for the time stamp, I can still spoof the system time on my device before your hashing function is run, thereby including my spoofed time stamp into your hash.

Comment: Good points. An old request in this case would mean someone trying to replicate a request made in the past and thus imply some sort of an attack. My approach is based on a standard set by Amazon in their Signature Version 4 Signing Process. It seems very graceful and secure.

Comment: I am familiar with AWS Signature4. AWS does reject any message that is greater than 5 minutes older than the current time, and that would, in fact, work against replay attacks. However, keep in mind that, for five minutes, that request WILL be subject to replay attacks. If you are performing a POST request against a RESTful endpoint, a fair amount of damage could be done within 5 minutes. An nonce would be the proper defense in that scenario.

Comment: While my company of employment is an AWS partner, I don't always agree with every aspect of their implementations.